# Problemas Con el metodo hasPermissions de Entrust en Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando laravel y entrust y miren el codigo de mi controlador>

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $role = $this->roleRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
    $permission=Permission::all();
    if (empty($role)) {
        Flash::error('Role not found');

        return redirect(route('roles.index'));
    }

    return   view('roles.edit')->with(['role'=>$role,'permission'=>$permission]);
}
```

Y este es el de la vista:

```
<select id="permission" type="text" class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" name="permission"  multiple required autofocus>
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach($permission as $per)

        <option value="{{$per->id}}"
           @if(isset($role))
               @if($role->hasPermission($per->name))
                   selected
               @endif
           @endif
        >{{$per->display_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Pero cuando cargo la vista me dice que :
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasPermission does not exist.
Que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 1):

La funcion estaba buena, pero debias compararla a 1, te dejare el codigo probado en mi local

```
<select id="permission" type="text" class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" name="permission"  multiple="multiple" required autofocus>
<option value=""></option>
@foreach($permission as $per)
    <option value="{{$per->id}}" @if(isset($role)) @if($role->hasPermission($per->name) == 1) selected="selected" @endif @endif>
        {{$per->display_name}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

**Navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero yo quiero saber si el Rol tiene el permiso no el ususario, los ususarios tienen roles y los roles permisos pero como lo que estoy haciendo es un crud para gestionar roles necesito saver que permisos tiene ese rol.. Help Me please

Comment: Ahhh ok ok entonces editare mi respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: A ver yo estaba usando hasPermission porque necesito comprovar uno a uno si un rol tiene un permiso determinado para que cuando la peticion regrese del metodo edit a la vista me cargue un multiselet con todos los permnisos que tiene ese rol, no se si em entiendes, mira el codigo que puse arriba a ver si ves por donde van mis intenciones

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione el problema es que como estoy utilizando Infyom para generar los CRUD tambien crea un Modelo aparte para el mapeo y no estaba utilizando EntrustRoleTrait la solucion es ponerle en el neuvo modelo `use EntrustRoleTrait` o simplemente cambiar la erencia en lugar de extender de Model extender de EntrustRole.